# OWIN Mixed Auth for staging environments

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, owin

Here's my scenario:
We have a standard MVC .net 5 site, which utilizes OWIN for the pipeline and authorization/authentication.

However we have a staging environment, which has an additional security precaution and wants to block all requests with an initial windows auth prompt as well.  This way, only the developers and testers can access this particular environment, but still get the rest of the normal functionality.

In previous iterations, this seems to have been simpler.  If I use a standard initial setup for forms authentication, that seems to conflict with an IIS setup that is also asking for a Win Auth prompt.

What is the proper way to tackle this scenario?  Do I need to actually code something in the OWIN pipeline and possibly also mess with my Authorize attributes?

Comment: Who are you looking to disable access for? You could just setup a site in IIS and not forward your ports or set up a public IP and you'd have an intranet site.

Comment: yeah, we generally do both port blocking, along with having a win auth challenge as well for our development environments.  The Port stuff is working fine, but the Win Auth challenge seems to conflict with the Forms Auth stuff setup in MVC and the pipeline.  I think there are ways we can rig this to get by securely - was just curious if there was a standard anyone has established at this point.

Comment: What I am saying is that you have the option to only open your site on a specific domain and anything else will return a 404 without the need to do an explicit win auth challenge. This would work to restrict access from the outside because it's just setting up an intranet.